# Is it poosible to achieve the Authorization_code flow as 2 legged in OAUTH2 ??

Tags: oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Is it poosible to achieve the Authorization_code flow as 2 legged in OAUTH2 ??

Any response would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization_code flow cant't be 2 legged. But you can refresh token without any user involvement.